# Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ArtifactNotFound"

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-monitor

I'm trying to add `AzureMonitor` to one of my VM's with terraform, but I'm getting the followin error:

> Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ArtifactNotFound" Message="The VM extension with publisher 'Microsoft.Azure.Monitor' and type 'Microsoft.Compute' could not be found."

Terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent" {        
      name                 = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
      publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
      type                 = "Microsoft.Compute"
      type_handler_version = "1.0"
    
      virtual_machine_id = var.target_vm
}
```

I have tryed adding this manually and checked out the publiser, type and version like so:

```
az vm extension list -g MyResourceGroup --vm-name MyVm
```

```
{
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "enableAutomaticUpgrade": null,
    "forceUpdateTag": null,
    "id": "/subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm/extensions/AzureMonitorWindowsAgent",
    "instanceView": null,
    "location": "uksouth",
    "name": "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent",
    "protectedSettings": null,
    "protectedSettingsFromKeyVault": null,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor",
    "resourceGroup": "rg",
    "settings": null,
    "suppressFailures": null,
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
    "typePropertiesType": "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  }
```

Whats wrong with my terraform script? fyi I tried `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute in your `az vm extension list` query shows that the Virtual Machine Extension [*type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-manage?context=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fcontext%2Fcontext&tabs=azure-portal) should be `AzureMonitorWindowsAgent`. But the attributes don't map one-to-one between the output of the `az vm extension list` command and the Terraform arguments. It still requires some translation, thus the type is:

```
"typePropertiesType": "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
```

As an example, the `type` key is a VM Extension, but that is the same as the terraform resource itself.

The other issue is that the [`type_handler_version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-extension-versions) latest for Windows is currently 1.10. See [list of versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-extension-versions).

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent" {
  name                 = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                 = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  virtual_machine_id = var.target_vm
}
```